# Javascript that works in Firefox and not IE...why?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I've searched all over to try to figure this one out, but just can't seem to.  My javascript code works in Firefox, but not in IE8.  Any ideas why?

DOCTYPE:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
function toggle() {
    document.getElementById('togglefield').style.display = "table-row";
    var offertype = document.getElementById('offertype1fsa').value;
    if (offertype === "SIF" || offertype === "") {
        document.getElementById('togglefield').style.display = "table-row";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('togglefield').style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="label" align="right">
            Offer Type
        </td>
        <td class="field" align="left">
      <select name="offertype1fsa" class="select" id="offertype1fsa" onchange="toggle();" >
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="PIF">PIF</option>
        <option value="SIF">SIF</option>
      </select>               
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="togglefield">
        <td class="label" align="right">
            Amount (if SIF)
        </td>
        <td class="field" align="left">
           <input type="text" name="sifamt1fsa" id="sifamt1fsa" />  
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3Pne/);

```
<script language="javascript">
function toggle(elem) {
    var offertype = elem.value;
    document.getElementById('togglefield').style.display =
        (offertype === "SIF" || offertype === "")? "":"none";
}
</script>
.
.
.

      <select name="offertype1fsa" class="select" id="offertype1fsa" onchange="toggle(this);" >
```

Comment: Works for me in IE8 without paying attention to the DOCTYPE - see the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z3Pne/)

Comment: Thanks - I upgraded from IE8 to IE9 AND used your script. Works exactly as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

> Note: The values "inline-table", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", "table-row-group", and "inherit" are not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.

Comment: @mplungjan  http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css#support-css2propsbasic-display   http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: @hart Thanks for the info - I didn't know that.  However, I am using IE8 and already have the following doctype declaration: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">